# Accessing an XML file stored in a PHP variable with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, xml

I'm new to programming, so please go easy on me =]

I'm sending a string from the user to an API using the below PHP. The API sends back an XML file and I'm storing it under `$response`. So far so good. 
Now, I'm breaking my head over, how to trigger a jQuery function based on the data on the XML.

As you can see below, I'm accessing `$response -> success`, and if `success == 1` I want to trigger some jQuery functions, and if `success` equals any other number, I want to trigger some other jQuery functions. How do I do it? Is it possible at all?

```
if(isset($_POST['user_string']) == 5){ 
    $post = 'data='.$data.'&key='.$key.'&format='.$format.'&mode='.$mode;
    $url = 'api2.apisite.com.';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($response -> success == 1) {

    } else {

    }
```

Thanks, a LOT!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP example you provided is a server-side call. jQuery is (typically) a client side call.

Instead of posting a form directly to the .php file, use jQuery.ajax() or jQuery.post() to fetch the .php file, passing 'user_string' as POST data. jQuery.ajax() can then check the return value of the Ajax response and act accordingly.